# Facing issue in setting up FBA in sharepoint 2010 foundation

Tags: 2010, forms-authentication

I have followed this procedure of creating fba from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg252020(v=office.14).aspx).

Now after trying to login in a site collection , it shows

> Error: Access Denied , Current User   You are currently signed in as: 
>   admin1   sign in as different user .

How should i resolve this ?